# Using two graphics cards

Tags: graphics-card

My current setup has an ATI A7000 graphics card.

I found an old Power Mac G4 with an ATI Radeon 7200 and was hoping I could install it ON my PC (win xp pro) to run two monitors.

Anyone know if this can be easily done/done at all? The MOBO is an Asus A8 (A8V maybe, can't remember) with an AMD Athlon 64 3000+ Processor.

Comment: Do those video cards support ATI CrossFire? It's ATI's version of SLI, using more than 1 video card at a time in unison. Also, the motherboard will need 2 PCIe/AGP slots, depending on the video card interface.

Comment: I don't know about the CrossFire. The cards will fit. [Here](http://ep.yimg.com/ca/I/extremepcgear_2128_255348223) is a pic of the A7000. And a pic of the 7200 [here](http://www.mac-s.co.jp/images/useditem/100511/514/FU1004291-5.jpg).

Comment: CrossFire is irrelevant to simply using multiple cards for multiple monitor outputs (and depending on how many outputs you want can actually be counterproductive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the card will physically fit in the machine (it has a spare slot) then yes, it should work.

I've currently got an ATI 4890 and a 4350 running at the same time, you don't have to use Crossfire.

Comment: Hrm, well...I can't get it to work. Device manager shows the new card in the list of Display Adapters as a second "Radeon 7000 Series" stating that the device can not be started (or something like that). Display Properties now shows two monitors but won't let me activate the second one (it tries, but fails). Any ideas of what to do?

Comment: Have you got drivers installed for the 7200?

Comment: Yup, I downloaded them from ATI but still no luck. I'll try again just to be sure.

Comment: +1 for not needing crossfire. - crossfire is used to combine the power of multiple gpu's into one, and isnt applicable for this application.

Comment: I'm uninstalling the old driver and then trying again. It looks like if it is going to work I'll just need the one driver.

Comment: Hmm.. Do you know that the card works? If so, I'm not really sure, but I would try putting the 7200 in as the main card to see if it actually works or not first.

Comment: Yah, the Power Mac G4 it took it from works with it in. I also took out the A7000 (current card) and booted with ONLY the 7200 (from the mac) and got nothing.

Comment: Just to make sure that I didn't break the card while installing/uninstalling I just tested it again on the mac: and it works.

Comment: Hm still no luck. The card is now being recognized as a Radeon 7200 (as it should) but I'm getting "This device cannot start. (Code 10)"

Comment: Tried another Mac graphics card and it doesn't work on my PC either. It must be something to do with the cards' bios being for Mac?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with these particular cards, but XP can have trouble with different GPUs playing nice. I'm willing to bet this would work fine under Vista/7.  I don't think it should matter that they were originally Mac cards, but I see you say the 7200 won't work on its own, so maybe I'm wrong.   If you only want two monitors, most any card on the market these days will do it anyway...you can pick up something cheap.